# How can I prove that $y= \sqrt {x} \sin{\frac 1x}$ on $(0,1)$ is uniform continuous only using $\epsilon-\delta$?

Tags: real-analysis

I have already proved that it is uniform continuous, since $f$ can be extended to the continuous function 
$$g :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$$ 
such that $f=g$ on $(0,1)$. But I can not prove it using only $\epsilon-\delta$ method.

help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easiest to do a proof by contradiction. Suppose there were some $\epsilon > 0$ such that no $\delta$ satisfied the uniform continuity condition. Then for each $n$ there would be an $x_n$ and $y_n$ in $(0,1)$ such that
$$|x_n - y_n| < {1 \over n} {\hskip 0.5 in} {\rm and} {\hskip 0.5 in}|f(x_n) - f(y_n)| > \epsilon$$
You can pass to a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ such that $x_{n_k}$ converges to some $a \in [0,1]$. Since $|x_{n_k} - y_{n_k}| < {1 \over n_k} \leq {1 \over k}$, you also have that $y_{n_k}$ converges to $a$.

If $a = 0$, then $f(x_{n_k})$ and $f(y_{n_k})$ both converge to zero, contradicting $|f(x_{n_k}) - f(y_{n_k})| > \epsilon$ for each $k$.

If $a \neq 0$, then $f(x_{n_k})$ and $f(y_{n_k})$ both converge to $\sqrt{a} \sin {1 \over a}$, once again contradicting $|f(x_{n_k}) - f(y_{n_k})| > \epsilon$ for each $k$.

Either way you have a contradiction and the claim is proven.

Comment: oh! I didn`t think at all using compactness. i think it is clear! thanks.